# How can I correct my list format?

Tags: python-2.7

first I write a test code:

```
a = [-0.2364, 2.2524, 8.4896,'a']
l = []
for i,each in enumerate(a,start=1):
    l.append(["{}, {}".format(i,each)])
lst = str(l).translate(None, "'")
print lst
```

and the output is ok

```
[[1, -0.2364], [2, 2.2524], [3, 8.4896], [4, a]]
```

This is what I want like add serial number for each item in a list. And then I try use `httplib` read data and replace test list `a`.

```
a = response.read()
l = []
for i,each in enumerate(a,start=1):
    l.append(["{}, {}".format(i,each)])
lst = str(l).translate(None, "'")
print a    
print lst
```

But output is changed like :

```
[-0.035308122832456316]
[[1, [], [2, -], [3, 0], [4, .], [5, 0], [6, 3], [7, 5], [8, 3], [9, 0], [10, 8], [11, 1], [12, 2], [13, 2], [14, 8], [15, 3], [16, 2], [17, 4], [18, 5], [19, 6], [20, 3], [21, 1], [22, 6], [23, ]]]
```

list`a` seems ok. but output`lst` is not what I expected.For this case I trying to get output like:

```
[-0.035308122832456316]
[[1,-0.035308122832456316]]
```

how can I fix this?Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the response you get is a list not a string? as seems like you are running your code on a string where each character in string is considered as list item of **a**.

Comment: yes. `[-0.035308122832456316]` this is my output about response()

Comment: Still I believe **a** is a string ''[-0.035308122832456316]'' try checking `type(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above if **a** is a string `'[-0.035308122832456316]'` or even with multiple list values like this  `a = '[-0.035308122832456316,89427873479875]'` simply use below code and it will work fine for you.

```
import ast
a = response.read()
a = ast.literal_eval(a) #Convert String representation of list to list
l = []
for i,each in enumerate(a,start=1):
    l.append(["{}, {}".format(i,each)])
lst = str(l).translate(None, "'")
print a    
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with a dictionary instead of a list:

```
a = [-0.2364, 2.2524, 8.4896, 'a']
l = {}
for i, each in enumerate(a, start=1):
    l[i] = each
print l
```

To simulate your indication that `a` is a list with 1 item:

```
a = [-0.035308122832456316]
l = {}
for i, each in enumerate(a, start=1):
    l[i] = each
print l
```

If, as others have indicated, that `a` is a string with value `"[-0.035308122832456316]"`, then convert it to a list:

```
a = "[-0.035308122832456316]"
if isinstance(a, str):
    a = [a[1:-1]]
l = {}
for i, each in enumerate(a, start=1):
    l[i] = each
print l
```